# Pass rich text editor value to bean

Tags: editor, javabeans, jdeveloper, jspx

I'm using Jdevloper 11g R2 and I have a .JSPX page that contains an ADF Rich Text Editor.

This editor can contain text and Images and different styles.

how can i pass the value of this editor to my bean?
my goal is to take this value and send it as a body in my email.

but how it can be stored? should it be saved as a string eventhough the editor have images?

any help is really appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create binding for the `RichTextEditor` which will be of type `oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.input.RichTextEditor`

as `private RichTextEditor myEditor;`

Write setter and getter methods for the component in your bean as below

> ```
> public void setMyEditor(RichTextEditor myEditor) {
>     this.myEditor= myEditor;
> }
>
> public RichTextEditor getMyEditor() {
>     return myEditor;
> }
> ```

Now you may access the value entered in the component with the getter method and use it as you wish.

Comment: yes this worked for me. i am using this code like this String myvalue = getTexteditor().getValue().toString()   here i am having the value inside the text editor normally. but what i want is that i want to get the html code of this text editor. in another meaning myvalue should receive the code value of the text editor. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `richTextEditor` is stored as CLOB type in database.